# HL7 - How to get POS (place of service code) codes details?

Tags: hl7, mirth

I need to get POS (Place of Service code set) related values from HL7. I tried a lot to find in different types of Message-Event-Segment, but not able to find it. please let me know in which Segment this value will occur.

Thanks,

Kunal Shah

Comment: HL7 might call it by a different than your application. Can you elaborate on POS?

Comment: POS means Place of Service Codes for Professional Claims. You can refer it on http://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/place-of-service-codes/Place_of_Service_Code_Set.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking in Charge message composition a DFT message type P03 event type-DFT^P03 to be precise.

Check for FT1 segments in the HL7 reference guide under FT1.16 - it is termed as Assigned patient location or place of service. Good luck!